# Is the picture isomorphic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, group-isomorphism

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCjB0.png)
Me and my frined were having a descussion i think this is not isomorphic.
What do you think and could you provide some more info about it?

Comment: They are isomorphic indeed. They have the same nmber of edges and vertices. Note that both have exactly one vertex with for edges, which connects it with th eother vertices, while the other for vertices form a "square".

Comment: Yeah but don't the number of angles be the same ?One has 4 while the other 7 ?

Comment: When you study graph theory there is no notion of "angle". What do you mean by 4 angles or 7 angles?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=(V,E)$ and $G‘=(V’,E‘)$ be two graphs. They are isomorphic if there is a bijection $\varphi: V \to V‘$ such that $(v_x, v_y) \in E \iff (\varphi(v_x), \varphi(v_y)) \in E‘$.

This means that, if we can find a bijective vertex mapping between $V(G)$ and $V(G‘)$, such that adjacency is preserved, then the given graphs are isomorphic. Can you go from here for the provided graphs?

**Edit:** The number of vertices, the number of edges, the degree sequence. and many more other properties must be the same in $G$ and $G‘$ in order for them to be isomorphic. These are necessary conditions. Take the number of vertices and edges, this follows directly from the defined isomorphism map. But these conditions are **not sufficient**, meaning you can have graphs having the same number of vertices and edges without them being isomorphic. We need a so called certificate in order to prove isomorphism (have a look at canonical labelling). However the complexity of the graph isomorphism problem is high (actually a precise classification is still missing, but we do not have efficient algorithms for general graphs).

Meaning, finding certificates such as canonical labellings is not faster for a small number of graphs than finding the isomorphism map directly. Since your provided problem is very easy, you should construct the isomorphism map directly.

For example: let $\varphi(v_5)=u_5$. Define the other mappings such that the definition provided is satisfied. (and of course, if some necessary condition fails, you can already state that the two graphs are not isomorphic).

Comment: Equal number of vertices.
Equal number of edges.
Same degree sequence
Same number of circuit of particular length                                                                                Should theese be the rules for getting the isomorphism i tried doing it like this but one rule does not apply.

Comment: These are particular invariants preserved under isomorphism. This is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: May it be possible to go thru a little more in depth?

Comment: I added some more details.